# SQL - NULL foreign key

Tags: sql, null, foreign-keys

Please have a look at the database design below:

```
create table Person (id int identity, InvoiceID int not null) 
create table Invoice (id int identity, date datetime)
```

Currently all persons have an `invoiceID` i.e. the `InvoiceID` is `not null`.

I want to extend the database so that some person does not have an `Invoice`. The original developer hated nulls and never uses them. I want to be consistent so I am wondering if there are other patterns I can use to extend the database to meet this requirement. How can this be approached without using nulls?

Please note that the two tables above are for illustration purposes. They are not the actual tables.

Comment: `NULL` is specifically *intended* for the case when you don't have a value - so in this case, I would argue using `NULL` is the most suitable approach.

Comment: Though I would usually agree with keeping consistency I completely disagree with `NULL hating` in dbs. This is definitely not an idea you want to propagate any further. It is silly and not at all constructive.

Comment: Can each Person only have one Invoice?  The way you have it, it seems like each invoice can have multiple people but not the other way around.

Comment: @ Paul Sasik, thanks.  I agree.  Although null is defined as unknown.  It is not unknown in this case.

Comment: This design seems to be upside down from normal expectations where you could expect a person to have zero or more invoices, and an invoice to relate to one and only one person. Unless you are selling people and the invoice relates to the sale OF a person and not TO a person...

Comment: @LordPeter which is another reason to add a PersonInvoice association table (or add the person_id to the Invoice table and remove invoice from the person) - but as OP says they are not the actual tables

Answer (score 5):

NULL is a very important feature in databases and programming in general.  It is significantly different from being zero or any other value.  It is most commonly used to signify absence of value (though it also can mean unknown value, but that's less used as the interpretation).  If some people do not have an invoice, then you should truly allow NULL, as that matches your desired Schema

Comment: Several well known practioners state that NULL is a terribly bad bug if you have it in a design - e.g. Chris Date. Does it mean absence of value or unknown and how does it affect select s and groupings?

Comment: NULL is an important feature - well, let's assume that is true (because I don't think this is the heart of the question). However, this question is not about "null in general" (e.g. to represent "missing data"), but rather it is about "null *foreign keys*" .. I think that, while it might make the model "slightly more complex", disallowing null FK's actually makes life more consistent. It also avoids "issues" with SQL Server where multiple NULL values are not considered distinct (e.g. in a unique index).

Comment: @Mark I mentioned those same two points -- being absent vs unknown/missing -- and I still stick to my answer.  I think it is important to have and best reflects what he wants to accomplish.  I realize some people say it's a bad design; I just tend to disagree and I stand by my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A common pattern would be to store that association in a separate table.

Person: Id
Invoice: Id
Assoc: person_id, assoc_id

Then if a person doesn't have an invoice, you simply don't have a row.  This approach also allows a person to have more than one invoice id which might make sense.

Comment: ps - I don't think "the original developer didn't like nulls so I won't use them" is a good reason to avoid nulls.

Comment: The caveat with this answer is that it does resemble a many-to-many relationship.  It doesn't have to be used that way!  This is a perfectly acceptable answer if you truly can't have NULLs.  But I would consider switching to NULL.

Comment: @EliGassert I've actually been moving *away* from NULL-FKs!

Answer (score 3):

The only way to represent the optional relationship while avoiding nulls is to use another table, as some other answers have suggested.  Then the absence of a row for a given Person indicates the person has no Invoice.  You can enforce a 1:1 relationship between this table and the Person table by making person_id be the primary or unique key:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonInvoice (
  person_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  invoice_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES Person(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES Invoice(id)
);
```

If you want to permit each person to have multiple invoices, you can declare the primary key as the pair of columns instead.

But this solution is to meet your requirement to avoid NULL.  This is an artificial requirement.  NULL has a legitimate place in a data model.

Some relational database theorists like Chris Date eschew NULL, explaining that the existence of NULL leads to some troubling logical anomalies in relational logic.  For this camp, the absence of a row as shown above is a better way to represent missing data.

But other theorists, including E. F. Codd who wrote the seminal paper on relational theory, acknowledged the importance of a placeholder that means either "not known" or "not applicable."  Codd even proposed in a 1990 book that SQL needed *two* placeholders, one for "missing but applicable" (i.e. unknown), and the other for "missing but inapplicable."

To me, the anomalies we see when using NULL in certain ways are like the undefined results we see in arithmetic when we divide by zero.  The solution is:  *don't do that*.

But certainly we shouldn't use any non-NULL value like 0 or '' (empty string) to represent missing data.  And likewise we shouldn't use a NULL as if it were an ordinary scalar value.

I wrote more about NULL in a chapter titled "Fear of the Unknown" in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: And if you haven't read Bill's book, I highly recommend you get a copy and read it. No one should be working on database designs and queries without being familar with the concepts in this book.

Comment: Thank you @HLGEM!  BTW, sorry for hawking my book on SO all the time, I try to do so only after I've given a genuine answer, or linked to some free resources.

Comment: We can also add a column that says whether the original column was null & when so set the original to some chosen value for its type. PS Codd's & SQL's n-VLs are what they are. They have pitfalls which are obviated & illustrated by the 2 null-free designs (and others). They also give a shorthand for some simple uses of the others. But outside such idioms (which do not compose) null use is more complex. Regardless, DBMSs could *present* the 3 design patterns as views of the others. PS Saying nulls "mean" something rather than support some things is misleading. *Rows* have meanings--statements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the invoice/person relation to another table.
You end up with

```
create table Person (id int person_identity) 
create table PersonInvoice (id int person_id, InvoiceID int not null)  
create table Invoice (id int identity, date datetime)
```

You need this for some databases to allow in InvoiceId to be a foreign key as some do not allow NULLS in a foreign key.

If a person only can have one invoice then PersonInvoice can have a unique constraint on the person_id as well as the two columns together. You can also enforce having a single person for a invoice by adding a unique constraint to the invoiceID field.

Comment: The join table pattern is only valid if you're going to have multiple Person(s) on a single invoice. If an Invoice can only have one person you do not need a separate table. Just a foreign key from Invoice to Person.

Comment: @PaulSasik It is not correct to assert that a Join Table is "only valid" in that case. While a Join Table *usually* represents M-M it can also represent 1-M and 1-1 relationships based on cardinality of the columns. In this case PersonInvoice would have a Unique(person_ID) and Unique(invoice_ID). (Read: each person can have one invoice and one invoice can be belong to at most one person.)