# Cannot INSERT because of Foreign key constraints - mysql

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

So I don't understand why I cannot insert data in my table that have foreign constraint keys or even modify anything in it.

Here is an example of the tables that are created. I am trying to insert data in the addresses table:

```
///////////////////////ADDRESSES TABLE ////////////////////////
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS addresses (
                id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                addressline1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                addressline2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                postcode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                phonenumber INT(13) NOT NULL,
                
                country_id INT NOT NULL,
                
                PRIMARY KEY (id),
                
                FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id)
                
                  ON UPDATE CASCADE
                  ON DELETE RESTRICT
                
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB ";

///////////////////////COUNTRIES TABLE ////////////////////////
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries (
                id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                countryname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

                PRIMARY KEY (id)
                
                )
```

Comment: Just a guess... are you trying to insert into addresses before you insert into countries?

Comment: Yes I do. So I can't insert in the child table before the parent one? What is the correct way to do it then? Because the addresses table is also a parent table for my Users table... Should I put the foreign keys of my table as NULL in order to fill datas without having issues? Also I cannot even set the country_id as NULL after tables have been created...?

Comment: 2. Also was wondering; does it make more sense to have the foreign key addresse_id in the users table or have a foreign key user_id in the addresses table...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to insert into a referencing table (addresses) when the referenced entry (the country you reference) does not exist. That's what's triggering the FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT exception.

Try first inserting some countries into the countries table, then inserting some addresses where you reference those countries you entered in the first step.

As for your second question, that's a choice for you to make. I would probably choose to have the User have an Address (address field in the User table), but some of that depends on how the data is being used/updated.

Have a quick look through [this resource](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html) if you're new to relational database design. It covers (in brief) topics like relationship types, key constraints, and normal forms.

Comment: Ok will do that in the right order then. I am new to working with the DB but not to the concept/relationships thus the errors... What if my user has no address when being created ? Is it good practice to set the foreign key as NULL when creating tables to avoid errors if no address is yet set up? Thanks a lot,

Comment: Try taking a look at [this stack overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885305/sql-null-foreign-key) to help with that question :)

Comment: Ok very helpful your link too for the examples on a complete database see [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/SampleDatabases.html). I have been looking for an example like that for a while now..!

Comment: I'm glad it's been helpful for you! Good luck on your project :)